# Javascript regex: only match the end of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find out multiline texts ending with "Tr ", "Br " and linebreak ("\n") without " _" (none-whitespace and underscore) preceded. Exmples

Text 1:

```
Command1 Br 
Command2 Tr 

"Command1 Br \nCommand2 Tr " //match "Tr " at the end
```

Text 2:

```
Command3 con Tr 
Command4 Br 

"Command3 con Tr \nCommand4 Br " //match "Br " at the end
```

Text 3:

```
Command2 Tr 
Command3 con Br 
Command4 C_

"Command2 Tr \nCommand3 con Br \nCommand4 C_\n" //match "\n" at the end after C_
```

Text 4:

```
Command1 Tr 
Command1 Br 
Command2 Tr _

"Command1 Tr \nCommand1 Br \nCommand2 Tr _\n" //no match because of " _" preceded "\n"
```

Text 5:

```
Command1 Tr 
Command1 Br 
Command2 mt

"Command1 Tr \nCommand1 Br \nCommand2 mt\n" //match \n at the end after "mt"
```

Text 6:

```
Command2 ht

"\n\nCommand2 ht\n" //match \n at the end after "ht"
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but it doesnt work with \n.

Comment: Out of 4 cases which one doesn't work with this regex?

Comment: Well! Maybe it's right with 4 exmples above however it's wrong when apply to others text. Your pattern doesnt find out linebreak ("\n") without " _" such as "Command3 con Br \nCommand4 C\n". I need the match of \n after "C"

Comment: Then you should provide all the details with better examples.

Comment: I already updated example. Hopefully I will receive useful advices from you. Thank!

Comment: Try this one: `^.*?(Tr |Br |(?<! _)\n)$`

Comment: Correction: `/^.*(Tr |Br |(?<!\s_)\n)$/si`

Comment: Abubhava! The problem is that pattern doesn't see \n (without " _" preceded) at the end of text.
Kalsowerus!  Your pattern has a problem that is "? The preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: @user3120188: Since there is no lookbehind support in JS regex, you need to precise: are you going to *extract* those matches, or *replace* them with some other text?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex to *extract* those matches:

```
/(?:^| [^_]|[^ ]_|[^ ][^_])([BT]r|\n)[\t ]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQe6UD/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:^| [^_]|[^ ]_|[^ ][^_])` - a non-capturing group matching one of the three alternatives:

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `|` - or
  - `[^_]` - space and any char but `_`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^ ]_`  - any char but space and `_`
  - `|`  - or
  - `[^ ][^_]` - any char but space and then any char but `_` (thus, no `space`+`_`)
- `([BT]r|\n)` - Capturing group 1: either `Br`, `Tr` or  a newline symbol
- `[\t ]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces (may be replaced with `[^\S\r\n]` for better hor. whitespace coverage)
- `$` - the very end of the string.

```js
var ss = ["Command1 Br \nCommand2 Tr ", "Command3 con Tr \nCommand4 Br ", "Command2 Tr \nCommand3 con Br \nCommand4 C_\n",
"Command1 Tr \nCommand1 Br \nCommand2 Tr _\n", "Command1 Tr \nCommand1 Br \nCommand2 mt\n", "\n\nCommand2 ht\n"];
var rx = /(?:^| [^_]|[^ ]_|[^ ][^_])([BT]r|\n)[\t ]*$/;
for (var s of ss) {
console.log("Looking for a match in: " + s);
  m = rx.exec(s);
  if (m) {
     console.log("Found: " + JSON.stringify(m[1], 0, 4));
  } else {
     console.log("No Match Found.");
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3120188: If the solution solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer.